# Can I print envelopes/address labels from Address Book?

Tags: printing, contacts

As Christmas approaches I'd like to send a letter to my friends and family. I currently have their contact information in Address Book. Is there a way to print envelopes with my contacts' mailing addresses from Address Book? If so, how would I do this? If not, is there a program that will interface with Address Book and do this? If it's not possible to do envelopes, would it possible to at least print labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Address Book has this functionality built in. First, create a group and drag the contacts you want to send mail to into that group:

[image]

Select the group, then go File -> Print. Under the Style menu, you will see that you have the option to print either envelopers or address labels. The Layout tab will let you configure what specific kind of labels or envelopes you have:

[image]